# Using Netty ( tcp ), sending message from client in android to server

Tags: android, tcp, netty

I successed connection bitween client in android and server.

but, when I want to send message like "hello" or whatever, message was disappear.

this is my client code:

```
group = new OioEventLoopGroup();

    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(group);
    b.channel(OioSocketChannel.class);
    b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast(handler);
        }
    });

    Channel ch = null;
    ChannelFuture f = null;
    try {
        f = b.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port)).sync();
        ch = f.channel();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ch.writeAndFlush("hello!");
```

and this is my server code:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
    channels.add(ctx.channel());
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("Welcome My Server");
    System.out.println(ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    try {
        while (in.isReadable()) {
            System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
            System.out.flush();
        }
    } finally {
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    }
}
```

when I connect, Server was printing 'connected client ip address'
but after that, 'hello' message is not printed in my server.
what is wrong? server? client?
I think encode, decode is not problem, cuz nothing received
please let me know how to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a String you need to put StringEncoder in the ChannelPipeline (on the client side). If you check the returned ChannelFuture of writeAndFlush(...) you will see it was failed.